# How to search the records for a particular word in a field in MS access?

Tags: ms-access

How to search the records for a required word in a field in MS access through query or forms?

Answer (score 2):

Considering you provided limited info you do the following:

```
SELECT column
FROM Table
WHERE column.value like "*word*"
```

If you are looking for the part of the word, you use a `*` in either the front/end of the value. It is your wildcard that allows you to find the word.

If you are looking for an exact word, you would just search directly for the word:

```
SELECT column
FROM Table
WHERE column.value = "word"
```

If you want to exclude records then:

```
SELECT column
FROM Table
WHERE column.value <> "word"
```

Comment: The .Value property is completely unnecessary in SQL.

Comment: I am aware it is unnecessary, I put that there as a reference based on the fact they provided no info.

Comment: Actually, there's one case in Access/ACE where it IS necessary, and that's if you are using multivalue fields. Now, nobody should be USING mv fields, but they exist, and for querying them you have to specify the .Value property.